# Modify a line's property set in XAML within code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question. I want to modify the height of a line created in XAML but in code, depending on a few conditions unrelated to the line itself. The XAML code for the line is as follows:

```
<Line
            Name="Linie5"
            X1="10" Y1="70"
            X2="670"  Y2="70"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="1"/>
```

Now when I go to the .cs file I want to select the line by it's name and modify it's height, all of this within a button_pressed event.

```
private void butonParametri_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Line l in canvas1.Children)
        {
            if (l.Name == "Linie5")
                l.Y2 = l.Y2 + 15;
        }
    }
```

The error I get is that an object of type label cannot be cast to an object of type line right in the foreach statement. How could I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas include child of other types (e.g. `Label`) but you are going to check names of `Line` elements and it cannot cast all of those children to `Line` so first you should get `Line` children then enumerate them.

Use `OfType<T>()` so only children with that type will be used in the foreach loop. Here is the code:

```
foreach (Line l in canvas1.Children.OfType<Line>())
{
    //identical to your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hossein, this did the trick with the code I already had. Clemens also gave me a hint on how to directly access a line's property without searching for it! Both answers were great !

Comment: @user2671364 glad to be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Set `x:Name` instead of `Name`

```
<Line x:Name="Linie5" ... />
```

and directly access the Line instance by the generated member variable in code behind:

```
Linie5.Y2 += 15;
```

Comment: Wow! So we should consider the problem not complicated then much much simpler solutions will arise.